# How do I persuade IE7 to show the "Accept ActiveX control" yellow bar?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, activex

Background: our IT gurus just upgraded the default browser on our desktops to IE7. Try not to be jealous at our state-ot-the-artfulness.

This would not normally be a problem since I use Firefox for my internet needs (3.5.3 happily downloading in the background as I type) but I have one site that uses Aventail's VPN ActiveX control to get me to a remote third-party application each day. Again, I'll use IETab within FF, but that too is now picking up IE7 and IE7 wants to reinstall the ActiveX.

Everything goes fine, the installer runs, then I'm told to accept the add-on by selecting "Run ActiveX Control" from the "yellow bar". And that's the problem: there is no "yellow bar".

Is the "yellow bar" a part of IE7, or am I getting info that's even more out-of-date than my brand-new browser?

If it is, what setting might I change to see it? (I've set everything in the Security Settings that relates to "ActiveX Controls and plug-ins" to "Enable" or "Prompt")

If the "yellow bar" is a thing of the past, is there some other way to accept the ActiveX control, or is it possible that the aforementioned IT gurus have completely screwed me?

Answer (score 2):

IIRC the yellow bar is there, but there is no saying it can't be turned off completely. The main point of the yellow bar is to allow you to override the block and allow ActiveX components in so your IT people may have locked down your install to stop this from happening.

Adding the relevant domain names to your "trusted sites" may do the trick, though again that may be something you as a user are locked out from so will need to request that IT do.